# How to retrieve a HTML page who was crawled using cache?

Tags: solr, information-retrieval, nutch

I'm using nutch1.3 to crawl some webpage and solr to generate each index. Performing a simple search on http://localhost:8983/solr/, it returns a result with various docs, each doc has some fields, I think these are the key to solve my problem:

> content: returns all the text crawled from the original html page, but unfortunately without the original html tags :(
>
> segment: returns the nutch segment where the data was extracted.
>
> digest: I think this field its the Solr's index for this page, because its unique and was generated by Solr.

The **main question** is: How I can retrieve the original HTML page using that I already cached? I think there is a way to use a combination of 'segment' and 'digest' fields to retrieve the cached html page, but act I'm not lucky to discover how.

ps1: I need this because I'm doing a offline search based on crawled html pages and need to show a 'cached view' like Google does.

ps2: On nutch 1.2 I was able to do it, using 'nutch-1.2.war' its possible to search a term and  there is a button 'cached' who shows a page (http://localhost:8080/nutch-1.2/cached.jsp?idx=0&id=5) with the cached page.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve raw HTML from Nutch index files by:

```
bin/nutch readseg -dump crawl-test/segments/.. dump -nogenerate 
-noparse -noparsedata -noparsetext
```

or in Java:

```
Configuration conf = NutchConfiguration.create(); 
SegmentReader reader = new SegmentReader(conf, true, false, false, 
false, false, false);  
reader.get();
```

Also this [link](http://dynamicguy.com/2010/09/nutch-cheat-sheet/) would be very helpful too. I should say I didn't work with Solr but only with Nutch, hope this helps.

Comment: not exactly what I was looking for but it's useful nonetheless!